# Is there a way to programmatically cancel editing a text box?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 App I have a single line textbox.  When the user presses {ENTER} I want to accept the textbox value  and switch the textbox back into normal non-edit mode.

Basically, is there a way to programmatically cancel editing a textbox?

I have tried force the Visual State Manager into Normal mode which does change the visual style, but the textbox is still in edit mode and on-screen keyboard is still showing.

```
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(
                this.MyTextBox,
                "Normal",
                true);

            VisualStateManager.GoToState(
                this.MyTextBox,
                "Unfocused",
                true);
```

Also tried to programmatically select a parent control but that doesn't seem to work either.

I think I must be missing something simple, someone must have done this a million times - any help much appreciated.

Thanks,

**Update**:  I tried to set focus to another Control but that wasn't working, the SIP keyboard would never disappear.

But I figured it out using another method.  The trick was to use the IsReadOnly flag.  When lost focus or enter was pressed I set the control back to read only which updates the style.  All I had to do was update my visual stlyes so it looked right and now works perfectly.

For what it's worth, my code now looks something like this:

```
    private void MyTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
        this.MyTextBox.SelectAll();            
    }

    private void MyTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyTextBox.IsReadOnly = true;
    }

   private void MyTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {

           this.MyTextBox.IsReadOnly = true;
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(
                this.MyTextBox,
                "ReadOnly",
                true);
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(
                this.MyTextBox,
                "Unfocused",
                true);
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(
                this.MyTextBox,
                "Valid",
                true);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Call Focus() on some other irrelevant control (maybe a Label?)
2. Disable then Enable the TextBox (feels hacky, but it works).

Comment: Instead of enabled I used "IsReadOnly" - but the same idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, based on Ben's answer:

```
private void SearchBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchBox.Text))
  {
    (sender as TextBox).IsEnabled = false;
    (sender as TextBox).IsEnabled = true;

    // Process search term here...
  }
}
```